# How to make a UserDetailsManager available as a bean

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-bean

I'm experimenting with spring-security for authentication and want to be able to add users at runtime. I figured using UserDetailsManager would be minimally intrusive. **How do I make it available as a bean, so that I can access it in controllers and other objects?**

The Code I was starting with is as follows:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource, PasswordEncoder enc) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withDefaultSchema().passwordEncoder(enc)
            .withUser("user").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

`jdbcAuthentication()` creates a `JdbcUserDetailsManager`, everything works fine. But I don't know to how to access that after the web app's initialization. I tried two variants that didn't work:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource,PasswordEncoder enc) throws Exception {
    return new JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<>().dataSource(dataSource).withDefaultSchema().passwordEncoder(enc)
            .withUser("user").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER", "ADMIN").and()
            .getUserDetailsService();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsManager);
}
```

When filling out the login form, I get the following:

```
Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
select username,password,enabled from users where username = ? [42102-185]
```

So it seems that this does not initialize the bean properly. Second try:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource, PasswordEncoder enc) throws Exception {
    return auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withDefaultSchema().passwordEncoder(enc)
            .withUser("user").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER", "ADMIN").and()
            .getUserDetailsService();
}
```

During initialization, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply ...JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer@3bd97b0d to already built object
```

So using the builder in an `@Bean` method does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jdbcAuthentication()` does more than just creating a `JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer`; most importantly, it registers the configurer using `apply()`, so that all configurations can later be executed in the right order.

Luckily, `apply()` is public, so we can call it ourselves. Knowing that, we can move the main configuration load back into `configureGlobal`, using the configurer's alternate constructor. What worked for me in the end is the following:

```
@Bean
public JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager mgr = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
    mgr.setDataSource(dataSource); // (1)
    return mgr;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager, DataSource dataSource, PasswordEncoder enc) throws Exception {
    //set user detail service manually
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsManager);
    JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> conf =
            new JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<>(userDetailsManager);
    //apply the configurer
    auth.apply(conf);
    conf.dataSource(dataSource) // (2)
            .withDefaultSchema().passwordEncoder(enc)
            .withUser("user").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password(enc.encode("password")).roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

It seems that setting the data source in (1) and (2) is redundant, but leaving either one out results in an exception during initialization:

```
//without (1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
//without (2)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataSource must be set
```

The first error is the validation of the bean returned by `userDetailsManager()`, the second that of the configurer before it is executed by the AuthenticationManagerBuilder.

Configured like this, I can write, e.g. in a controller:

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsManager users;
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder enc;

@RequestMapping(...)
public String handle(Model model) {
    users.createUser(new User(username, enc.encode(password), authorities);

    return "view";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you want to create a bean that handles users, i would suggest declaring it in the spring.xml and using functions that keep adding to the bean.
 try using an applicationcontext, this will be on main page

```
ApplicationContext ac;
        ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
        prisontest par=(prisontest)ac.getBean("prison");
```

here, applicationcontext is like a container holding beans and prisontest is class that defines the datasource, u can understand seeing the spring.xml,

the spring.xml will look in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="prison" class="prisontest">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/tgmc" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and the bean that refers to the datasource will be like this:

```
public class prisontest {
        DataSource ds;
        public void setDataSource(DataSource ds)
        {
            this.ds=ds;
        }
```

add your code here for managing users on runtime
    }

you can also put your other code in the same class, hope this helps.

Comment: This is not the problem I'm facing. I can create custom beans (though I prefer Java over XML for it), and can inject them just fine, so no need for using `ApplicationContext.getBean()`. My problem is precisely with the `JdbcUserDetailsManager`, which is created by `auth.jdbcAuthentication()`. I just struggle to get it out of the `configureGlobal()` method, as stated in the question.

Comment: i havent tried this but looks like your second variant can be corrected by creating a global reference to the already built in object. best of luck with the solution ill let you know if I find out anything.